# How to detect touch on view which appears when finger is on screen?

Tags: ios, uiview, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

For example: I have `UIView` and I detect long press - so then new `UIView` appears. It takes whole screen now. I still have finger down on the screen - I can move finger but I can't move up, beacause then my new `UIView` will disappear. So now I have to detect touches on my new `UIView` but neither touchesBegan nor `touchesMoved` is being called. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Code of my new `UIView`:

```
#import "Menu.h"

@implementation Menu
{

  //  int x;
  // int y;
  UIGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture;

}



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  NSLog(@"initWithFrame");
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [self setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
   longPressGesture = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]
                       initWithTarget:self
                      action:@selector(longPressBegan:)];

   [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

  }
return self;
}


-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   NSLog(@"TOUCHES BEGAN");
}
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  NSLog(@"TOUCHES MOVED");
}

-(void)longPressBegan:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
   NSLog(@"LONG PRESS");
 }
```

And none of these methods (touchesBegan, touchesMoved,longPressBegan) is called.

Comment: Add new UIGestureRecognizer to appeared UIView?

Comment: Tried this. Also doesn't work. I suppose because of finger is still on screen and new UIView doesn't receive action touches down?

Comment: Are you using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: yes, but also tried other recognizers

Comment: @Jastine, what about changing numberOfTouches (fingers used for detecting touches)? Will be great to see some code which shows new UIView, which precesses touches.

Comment: edited my question, so you can see code of new UIView now.

Comment: Instead of shuffling responders, you can process events at the object that receives it. In this case it would be the view with a long touch recogniser, in general it might be your `UIWindow`. From there you can delegate events or do the other stuff you want.